# SAS - creating new dataset on specific variable values from old dataset

Tags: sas

---

Hello:

I have a dataset of patient claims, and would like to create a new set of just those patient claims that have a diagnosis of alcohol use. I have put those alcohol diagnosis codes in a new dataset, and tried to run it against the larger set of patient claims to create the new one.

Below is the code I have been trying:

```
data alcohol;
  input code;
  datalines;
30300
30301
30302
30303
30390
30391
30392
30393
30501
30500
30502
30503
;

data alcohol;
  set alcohol;
  code1 = put(code, 5.);
  output;
run;

/*inpatient records with these codes*/
proc sql;
  create table alcin as
  select b.*
  from allpreg as b
  where 
    diag1 in (select code1 from alcohol) or 
    diag2 in (select code1 from alcohol) or 
    diag3 in (select code1 from alcohol) or 
    diag4 in (select code1 from alcohol) or 
    diag5 in (select code1 from alcohol) or 
    diag6 in (select code1 from alcohol) or 
    diag7 in (select code1 from alcohol) or 
    diag8 in (select code1 from alcohol) or 
    diag9 in (select code1 from alcohol);
quit;
```

Is there a better way to do this, or does this work?
Thanks!

Comment: This question doesn't really fit StackOverflow's guidelines.  Please read the guidelines here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask.  That doesn't mean that it isn't a good question, though.  It just doesn't fit.

Comment: How about transpose and use a join

Comment: How would I use that code?

Comment: You can post this at communities.sas.com or even search there for several ways of doing this. Here's a link to a partial method that transposes to a patient-diagnostic code level and then you can have only one IN statement in your WHERE clause. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28439907/frequency-of-a-value-across-multiple-variables

Comment: @EricTaylor That comment doesn't seem very helpful.  What about the question do you think doesn't fit within the guidelines?  What could improve the question?

Comment: @Joe "Is there a better way to do this" and "Does this work?" are problematic under the guidelines for two reasons. The first question will tend to produce answers that trade primarily on opinion, and the second question is a corollary of "Why doesn't my code work?".  The OP isn't clear on why the current "way" is deficient in some way, or why he thinks there may be a "better" way.  He's also not clear on what "works" means.  My answer might have been a bit curt.  My apologies.

Comment: @EricTaylor  Thanks for clarifying.  It's always better to have actionable suggestions when you make a comment like 'this question doesn't really fit', so that the asker can improve in the future!

Comment: @Joe Totally agree.  I really like reviewing and setting folks on the right path here on SO.  But sometimes I'm a little hasty, I think.

Answer (score 2):

One problem with your data is the structure: having 9 different diagnosis codes as variables can be difficult to work with, because you have to write the comparison out nine times, and if you ever add a 10th diagnosis code column, you have to change all of your code again.  A better structure would have one row per diagnosis.  PROC TRANSPOSE can get you there, or the data step; the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28439907/frequency-of-a-value-across-multiple-variables) is a good example of just that.  If you need all nine codes on the output dataset, you can still do this (And then merge/join the result table to the original table to get the qualified rows), or you may prefer not to change the structure.

However, regardless of your structure, you have a separate issue; that of how to best combine two tables.  That's what you are doing, after all.  Your method is one acceptable method, particularly when the list is relatively short; since the subquery will not take very long to run with only a handful of alcohol codes, it's not a bad solution.

A better solution in this case is a `format`.  You can turn your alcohol code list into a format, which can then be used with `put` to evaluate whether a row should qualify.  (I include a subset of codes below for brevity, you can write the complete list.)

```
proc format;
  value $alcoholdrg
   '30300','30301','30302','30303'= 'Alcohol'
    other='Not Alcohol';
quit;
```

Then you can use it easily:

```
proc sql;
  create table alcin as
  select   b.*
  from  allpreg as b
  where put(diag1,$ALCOHOLDRG.) = 'Alcohol';
quit;
```

(Again, I include one diag for brevity, you would need all nine or to restructure your data to make this work.)

Given you're working with ICD codes, I would look around online for code or articles related to working with them; there are some complexities related to how the subcodes work that might make this more complicated, and there is undoubtedly advice for how to work with this sort of problem readily available on more specialized sites.