# SAS -Making a new variable if conditions match another variable?

Tags: sas

I would like to make a new variable in my dataset. This variable is just a binary variable if someone has a tobacco disease or not. I am looking at patient data with each patient having up to 9 disease codes. I have a dataset called tobacco that stores all the tobacco disease codes.

This is what I thought I could do:

```
data outpreg;
set outpreg;
if diag1 = tobacco OR diag2 = tobacco OR diag3 = tobacco or diag4 = tobacco or diag5 = tobacco or diag6 = tobacco or 
diag7 = tobacco or diag8 = tobacco or diag9 = tobacco then co2=1;
run;
```

But this is giving me too many for it to be correct.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can't use tobacco in that manner, you need to either merge or use a lookup somehow.  We need more information on how the data sets are structured if you need more help.

Comment: Merge - "tobacco" and "patient" dataset on the primary key or common variable between them and then you could use your code with a little modification - tobacco would be in quotes

Answer (score 1):

It's not doing what you want to do. Your current code is trying to compare the value of `diag1` to a variable named `tobacco` in the same `outpreg` data set. Since there is no variable `tobacco`, SAS is creating a new variable `tobacco` and initializing it to missing `.`. In order to do what you want, I would join the `outpreg` data set to the `tobacco` dataset for each `diag` variable.

```
proc sql;
select
  o.*,
  t1.tobacco_cd is not null or
  t2.tobacco_cd is not null or
  t3.tobacco_cd is not null as co2
from
  outpreg as o
  left join tobacco as t1
  on o.diag1 = t1.tobacco_cd
  left join tobacco as t2
  on o.diag2 = t2.tobacco_cd
  left join tobacco as t3
  on o.diag3 = t3.tobacco_cd
;
quit;
```

This checks each `diag` variable against the list of codes, setting `co2` to `1` if it matches, and `0` if it doesn't. For example, if `diag1` matches, then `t1.tobacco_cd is not null` would be true, and the entire expression evaluates to `1`.

You'd have to expand it to cover all nine of your variables instead of just three.

Another option is to put your tobacco codes into a format like Joe suggested in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28485297/sas-creating-new-dataset-on-specific-variable-values-from-old-dataset).

```
proc format;
  value $tobaccocd
   '30300','30301','30302','30303'= 'Tobacco'
    other='Not Tobacco';
quit;
```

Then you could create your `co2` variable in a data step like this:

```
data outpreg2;
  set outpreg;
  if put(diag1,$tobaccocd.) = 'Tobacco' or
     put(diag2,$tobaccocd.) = 'Tobacco' or
     put(diag3,$tobaccocd.) = 'Tobacco' then co2 = 1;
  else co2 = 0;
run;
```